# IComparer classes for custom class

Tags: c#, comparison

I have a bunch cards in a List, and I want to sort them ascending or descending:

```
private List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
```

Ascending/descending would mean I would have to compare the values of the cards, simply.

What do I do? The IComparable interface seems to be not enough because it can only sort one "default" way. So I am trying to implement `IComparer`, but fail. In the same class file as Card, I try to add this comparing class for descending order:

```
public class CardCompDesc : IComparer<Card> {
    int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
        // return 0, -1, or -1 later
        return 0
    {
}
```

But already here the compiler complains that it cannot find IComparer in the current context. If I remove `<Card>` from the definition, the class compiles. However in order to be able to sort the cards above, something like this: `this.cards.Sort(new CardCompDesc());` it looks like I will have to use the IComparer<> over IComparer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`IComparer<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. Are you sure you've imported that?

Comment: Also, the signature of the Compare-method is incorrect. It should be `int Compare(Card a, Card b)` and not an explicit interface implementation.

Comment: You can also use Linq OrderBy extension method to sort the list ascendingCards = cards.OrderBy(c=> c.Name).ToList(); descendingCards = cards.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Name).ToList();

Comment: J. Steen: thanks, that was my first mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just grabbed a compare that I use that works.. here is the gist of it...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyComparer: IComparer<int>
    {
        public int Compare(int x, int y)
        {
            // x is greater move it up
            if (x > y)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            // x is smaller move y up
            if (x < y)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            // do nothing (equal)
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an off topic, but why do you need comparer for int?

Comment: @PawełReszka You don't, but the things I had in there would not have made sense in this context. I could have chosen any type to use, I just thought that an `int` was the simplest way to describe how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, I used the wrong "using" and had some mistake with the  signature of the Compare-method as per the comments above too. Btw System.Linq isn't really needed right?

Comment: @Jonny All good mate. Nah Linq isn't required. Like I stated it was just a cut'n'paste from a class I had already written. Pretty much only need `System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the two distinct types [`System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) and [`System.Collections.IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx). Note that they are in distinct namespaces and the first one has one type parameter (called `` IComparer`1[T] `` by .NET) while the second one is non-generic.

There is no need to use the non-generic type.

So do:

```
public class CardCompDesc : IComparer<Card> {
    int IComparer<Card>.Compare(Card a, Card b) {
        // return 0, -1, or -1 later
        return 0;
    }
}
```

if you insist on doing this with explicit interface implementation. However, why not simply implement by a `public` method, as in:

```
public class CardCompDesc : IComparer<Card> {
    public int Compare(Card a, Card b) {
        // return 0, -1, or -1 later
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Actually, it is maybe better to specify the base class `Comparer<Card>` (no `I`) instead:

```
public class CardCompDesc : Comparer<Card> {
    public override int Compare(Card a, Card b) {
        // return 0, -1, or -1 later
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In that way your `CardCompDesc` instace will be **both** `IComaparer<Card>` and (non-generic) `IComparer`, and you still have to write only one method in the class.

Finally, if you are OK with writing your single method as an arrow `=>`, you do not even have to write your own class. You can simply say:

```
this.cards.Sort((a, b) => {
        // return 0, -1, or -1 later
        return 0;
    });
```

If you want the `Comparer<>` instance created from the arrow, it is:

```
var yourComparer = Comparer<Card>.Create((a, b) => {
        // return 0, -1, or -1 later
        return 0;
    });
```